# Add text to outer ticks of a D3 axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

When creating a basic axis using d3, it seems that d3 is doing a nice job of choosing what ticks and values to display.
When I have a domain with ugly values (e.g 4.4 instead of 0), it will not display any text for the outer ticks, as intended.

My question is, how can I add some custom text for the outer ticks? (or maybe in the left and right sides of the axis, not necessarily bellow it)

```js
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([4.4, 989.4]).range([0, 600]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(scale);

d3.select('.axis')
 .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
 <svg width="650" height="40">
  <g class="axis" transform="translate(20, 0)" />
 </svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can force d3 to show outer ticks using [`.nice`](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#continuous_nice) method. Excerpt from the documentation:

> Extends the domain so that it starts and ends on nice round values.
>   This method typically modifies the scale’s domain, and may only extend
>   the bounds to the nearest round value.

```js
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([4.4, 989.4]).range([0, 600]).nice();

var axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(scale);

d3.select('.axis')
 .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
 <svg width="650" height="40">
  <g class="axis" transform="translate(20, 0)" />
 </svg>
```

You also can set `tickValues` for your axis this way (in this case scale domain will not be modified):

```js
var scale = d3.scaleLinear().domain([4.4, 989.4]).range([0, 600]);

var tickValues= [].concat(scale.domain()[0], scale.ticks(), scale.domain()[1]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom().scale(scale).tickValues(tickValues);

d3.select('.axis')
 .call(axis);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
 <svg width="650" height="40">
  <g class="axis" transform="translate(20, 0)" />
 </svg>
```

Comment: Oh, I get it, but what if I want to keep the domain unchanged?

Comment: It is also possible. I updated my answer, check, please.

Comment: Now this is an interesting approach. scale.ticks() always consists of the tickValues that d3 will display?

Comment: @bgiuga Exactly.